# Meaning of an $a^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

-- Edited --

For $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $a^T a$ means its norm. What does mean $a a^T$?

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: The superscript $T$ usually indicates transpose. What is $a$, in this context? A vector?

Comment: Are we to assume that $a$ is a column vector, and that $a^T$ is its transpose?

Comment: If $a$ is a unit vector, then $aa^T$ is the matrix of orthogonal projection onto the line of $a$.

Comment: $a^Ta=\operatorname{trace}(aa^T)$

Comment: "For $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $a^Ta$ means its norm. And $a a^T$?" Would be a better question

Comment: $a^Ta$ is the norm $\color{red}{\text{squared}}$.

Comment: Related to [outer product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matrix, viz. $(aa^T)_{ij}=a_i a_j$. If $n>1$, this matrix is singular because the $i$th row is $a_i$ times $a^T$.

Comment: Is there any geometrical/algebraic interpretation for it?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto If $a$ is normalized ($\|a\|=1$) then $aa^T$ is the [orthogonal projection to the line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas).

Comment: By orthogonal projection, do you mean "Given an arbitrary vector b and u an unitary vector, $b^{\perp u}$ may be given by $u u^{T} b$"?